Почему не обновляется ItemsControl?
Кто знаком с WPF (паттерн MVVM) можете ли мне подсказать как решить проблему с привязкой коллекции. Есть окно и  в окне элементы , а в их Content атрибут привязаны мои страницы .xaml, в одной из страниц есть ItemsControl, к которому привязана коллекция, и при её обновлении, содержимое не меняется. Сразу скажу что всё я привязал правильно и что коллекция обновляется методом Add и является типом ObservableCollection, но дополню что моя страница отрисовывает коллекцию при инициализации конструктора ViewModel. Ниже прикрепил код
MainWindow.xaml (именно она открывается):
<Window x:Class="GraphMaster.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GraphMaster"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="150" Width="0.7*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.5*"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        
        <Frame Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="6"
               Content="{Binding EditPanelView}"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                   DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
        <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
                Grid.RowSpan="6" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="1 1 0 0">
            <Frame Content="{Binding GraphView}"/>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Window>

MainWindow.xaml.cs:
using GraphMaster.Views;
using System.Windows;

namespace GraphMaster
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public EditPanelView EditPanelView { get; set; }
        public GraphView GraphView { get; set; }

        public MainWindow(EditPanelView editPanelView, GraphView graphView)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = this;
            
            EditPanelView = editPanelView;
            GraphView = graphView;
        }
    }
}

GraphView.xaml:
<Page x:Class="GraphMaster.Views.GraphView"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GraphMaster.Views"
      xmlns:shape="clr-namespace:GraphMaster.Models.Shapes"
      xmlns:cnv="clr-namespace:GraphMaster.Converters"
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
      Title="GraphView">
    <Page.Resources>
        <cnv:ConverterPointsCollection x:Key="ConverterPointsCollection"/>
    </Page.Resources>
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding GraphFragments, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            <ItemsControl.Resources>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type shape:CurveLine}" ItemsSource="{Binding Points}">
                    <Polyline Points="{Binding Points, Converter={StaticResource ConverterPointsCollection}}"
                          Stroke="{Binding Fill}"
                          StrokeThickness="{Binding Thickness}"/>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.Resources>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Page>

BaseViewModel.cs:
using GraphMaster.Models;
using GraphMaster.Services;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace GraphMaster.ViewModels
{
    public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private protected ILoggerService logger;
        private SmartDictionary repository { get; set; } = new SmartDictionary();
        public SmartDictionary Repository
        {
            get => repository;
        }

        public BaseViewModel(ILoggerService logger)
        {
            StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace();
            MethodBase? callingMethod = stackTrace.GetFrame(1)?.GetMethod();
            this.logger = logger;
            if(callingMethod?.DeclaringType != null) this.logger.Owner = callingMethod.DeclaringType;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string prop = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }
    }
}


GraphViewModel.cs
using GraphMaster.Models;
using GraphMaster.Models.Shapes;
using GraphMaster.Services;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Windows;

namespace GraphMaster.ViewModels
{
    public class GraphViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        private ObservableCollection<Shape> graphFragments = new ObservableCollection<Shape>();
        public ObservableCollection<Shape> GraphFragments
        {
            get => graphFragments;
            set
            {
                graphFragments = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(GraphFragments));
            }
        }

        private int canvasWidth;
        public int CanvasWidth
        {
            get => canvasWidth;
            set
            {
                canvasWidth = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CanvasWidth));
            }
        }
        private int canvasHeight;
        public int CanvasHeight
        {
            get => canvasHeight;
            set
            {
                canvasHeight = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CanvasHeight));
            }
        }

        public GraphViewModel(ILoggerService logger) : base(logger)
        {
            Repository.CollectionChanged += OnCollectionChanged;
        }
        
        public void UpdateGraph()
        {
            object? graph = ((GraphFactory?)Repository["GraphFactory"])?.Build();
            if (graph != null)
            {
                CurveLine result = (CurveLine)((IDrawable)graph).Draw();
                CanvasWidth = result.Width + 50;
                CanvasHeight = result.Height + 50;
                Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {
                    GraphFragments.Add(result);
                });
                logger.Info($"Count: {GraphFragments.Count}");
            }
        }
        private void OnCollectionChanged(object? sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Repository.Contains("GraphFactory"))
                Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => UpdateGraph());
        }
    }
}

Прикреплять GraphView.xaml.cs и EditPanelView.xaml.cs я не буду, так как там просто привязываются ViewModel этих вьюшек с помощью внедрения зависимостей

Page и Frame это не про MVVM. Ну а так, прикладывайте все нужное к вопросу, допустим, что такое Repository, как инициализируется GraphViewModel (включая ее страницу), вызывается-ли вообще метод обновления (у вас там лог вон есть logger.Info($"Count: {GraphFragments.Count}");), и так далее. Сейчас, тако впечатление, что вы делаете 2 разных объекта, где один выводится, а другой обновляет данные, из-за чего и нету видимых обновлений, ну а тут надо знать как эти объекты все создаются. В любом случае, делайте минимальный и самодостаточный пример, на голом WPF, полученный код кидайте сюда.

@EvgeniyZ Repository это объект класс SmartDictionary, и он выполняет функции оповещения о изменении Dictionary<K, T> (своего рода ObservableCollection только для словарей). Я решил не прикладывать сюда страницы с MainWindow.xaml.cs так как появились бы ещё вопросы, кратко обьясню что там инициализируются объекты GraphView.xaml и EditPanelView.xaml, а запутались бы вы ещё больше так как к проекту прикручена внедрение зависимостей. Все эти детали я опустил, чтобы получить ответа также от людей которые в этом не разбираются, но раз уж вам надо, я добавил

@EvgeniyZ И почему это Page и Frame это не про MVVM? Я это впервые слышу так как эту тему с главным окном и страницами просто пришло в голову, вот я и реализовал. Разве MVVM не подразумевает разделение бизнес логики и визуального представления приложения? Мне кажется что в моём случае всё вполне нормально

Я вам уже сказал свои мысли по поводу вашей проблемы. Делай минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример на голом WPF проекте, который будет иметь только то, что относится к конкретной проблеме. Полученный код в вопрос. Сейчас я не вижу как объекты создаются, из-за чего я думаю, что у вас создается два разных объекта, один который выводится на экран, а в другом меняются данные. Но это все догадки. Почему Frame не для MVVM я писал тут.

@EvgeniyZ Спасибо, я прочитал ваш пост, и понял что вы имели ввиду насчёт "Page и Frame это не про MVVM". К счастью я решил свою проблему с помощью логов, оказалось что при инициализации сервисов, я забыл указать что GraphViewModel.cs и остальные вьюшки, не являются синглтоном, отчего любое получение сервиса и его использование приводит к созданию нового объекта)

Как я и предполагал) На будущее, пожалуйста, минимальный пример, который любой человек сможет запустить у себя и изучить проблему. Без этого, увы, только тыкать пальцем в небо, что не есть хорошо. Да и пытаясь написать такой пример, вы сами абстрагируетесь от кучи лишнего и скорей всего быстро сами найдете проблему.
